# Combinations questoin

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am confused at how to approach the following problem:

There are 3 different marble colors: black, white, and red. If each color has atleast 8 marbles, how many ways can you select 3 marbles?

Is it C(24,3) +C(25,3).... or is there some other way to do this?

Comment: Are the marbles distinguishable or not? If they aren't, then the problem only ask what color could you have, e.g. `bbb` or `bbr`, ...

Comment: You should reproduce the **exact** textbook/assignment word by word. As it stands, it can be interpreted in many different ways, so no useful guidance is really possible.